# Facebook SDK v5 integration with Laravel 5.0

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-5, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

I'm trying to make a guide on how to integrate Facebook SDK v5 with Laravel 5.0. Have anyone done this before?

First of all i added "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "~5.0" in composer.json see documentatione here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted

```
{
  "require" : {
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "~5.0"
  }
}
```

Next step composer install in CMD

```
composer install
```

Next i added a route:

```
Route::get('/test', 'Facebookintegration@test');
```

Next i returned a view:

```
public function test() {

    return view('testpage');

}
```

Next i try to run the info in the view testpage

```
<?php

require_once URL::asset('vendor/autoload.php');

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
'app_secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

?>
```

Here is where the problems start and this is my current error

```
main(): Failed opening required 'http://localhost/fbintegration/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')
```

anyone know how to correctly link yo the files?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk

Use this package for Laravel instead.

The code below is to post to facebook after retrieving token from my DB

Route

```
  Route::post('schedulePost', 'HomeController@ exampelSchedulePost');
```

Composer.json

```
 "require": {
            "sammyk/laravel-facebook-sdk": "^3.0"
        }
```

Provider and aliases , refer to Docs

```
'providers' => [
    SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdkServiceProvider::class,
    ];

'aliases' => [
    'Facebook' => SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\FacebookFacade::class,
    ];



public function exampelSchedulePost(Request $request)
      { 
         $postPermission = 0;
         $profileToken = DB::table('profiles')->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
          $fb = App::make('SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdk');
         if($profileToken){
          try {
            $response = $fb->get('/'.$profileToken->uid.'/permissions', $profileToken->access_token);
            $permissions = $response->getGraphEdge();
            foreach ($permissions as $item) {
              if($item['permission'] == 'publish_actions'){
                if($item['status']== 'declined'){
                  $login_link = $fb->getLoginUrl(['email,publish_actions'], 'http://www.URL.com/facebook/callback');
                  return redirect($login_link);
                  //Get Permission again
                }
              }
            }
          } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
          }
         }else{
           $login_link = $fb->getLoginUrl(['email,publish_actions'], 'http://www.URL.com/facebook/callback');
           return redirect($login_link);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the path issue when you want to require file in your view.

You can try something like this in you view template:

require_once ($app['path.base'].'/vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php');

And the I believe you can get Facebook\Facebook class without problem.